# Make a global sidebar?

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I'm new at web programming was was wondering if you guys could help me. What I want I guess must be easy, but can't really find /how/.

I have my cute little sidebar that isn't even finished and is constantly needing to be changed. I already gave up on updating it until everything is ready:

```
<!-- sidebar menu -->
            <div id="sidebar-menu" class="main_menu_side hidden-print main_menu">
                <div class="menu_section">
                    <h3>General</h3>
                    <ul class="nav side-menu">
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a href="#l">Search</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Lookup</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-cubes"></i> Inventory <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a href="rawassets.php">Asset List</a>
                                <li><a>Asset Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                        <li class="create.php"><a href="#">Create Assets</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="update.php">Update Assets</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Tickets <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a href="Tickets.php">Ticket Overview</a>
                                <li><a>Ticket Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">Create a Ticket</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Update a Ticket</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>

                                <li><a>User Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                        <li class="sub_menu"><a href="#">User List</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Create a User</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Update a User</a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        <li><a><i class="fa fa-laptop"></i> Loans <span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                            <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                <li><a>Loan Management<span class="fa fa-chevron-down"></span></a>
                                    <ul class="nav child_menu">
                                        <li class="create.php"><a href="#">Create a Loan</a>
                                        </li>
                                        <li><a href="update.php">View Loans </a>
                                        </li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

            </div>
            <!-- /sidebar menu -->
```

But the problem is that I'm doing it like an uncultured swine and keeping that in every single page where it is needed. And if I want to make a change, I need to edit every single page.

I was wondering if there was a way to have a class, or something, with my header, sidebar, and footer, and load them across all pages that needed them?

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract the sidebar code into its own PHP file (sidebar.php) then include it where you need it with [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php) or [include_once](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include-once.php)

```
<html>
...
<body>
<?php include './sidebar.php' ?>
...
</body>
</html>
```

Using include is essentially the same as copy pasting the code into your file. I.e. It will be added where you include the code and it will be evaluated there as well

Answer (score 0):

Its very simple, Save you sidebar in a php file lets call it `sidebar.php`, and add below code in your other PHP file where you want to show the sidebar.

```
<?php include_once('sidebar.php');?>
```

That's it.